# Turning a band of Sentinel 2 image into an array

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am new to Google Earth Engine and have started playing with mathematically combining different bands to define new index. The problem I am having is the visualisation of the new index - I need to define the max and min parameter when adding it to the map, and I am having troubles understanding what these two end points should be. So here come my two questions:

1. Is it possible to get the matrix of my image in terms of pixel values? Then I could easily see from what values they range and hence could define min and max!
2. What values are taken in different bands? Is it from 0 to 1 and measures intensity at given wavelength, or is it something else?

Any help would be much appreciated, many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to get the matrix of my image in terms of pixel values? Then I could easily see from what values they range and hence could define min and max!

If this is what you want to do, [there's a built in way to do it.](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/playground#layer-manager) Go to the layer list, click on the gear for the layer, and in the “Range” section, pick one of the “Stretch:” options from the menu, then click “Apply”. You can choose a range in standard deviations, or 100% (min and max).

You can then use the “Import” button to save these parameters as a value you can use in your script.

(All of this applies to the region of the image that's currently visible on screen — not the entire image.)

> What values are taken in different bands? Is it from 0 to 1 and measures intensity at given wavelength, or is it something else?

This is entirely up to the individual dataset you are using; Earth Engine only knows about numbers stored in bands and not units of measure or spectra. There may be sufficient information in the dataset's description in the [data catalog](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog), or you may need to consult the original provider's documentation.

Comment: Thank you very much! This has been very helpful - do you by chance have any other suggested ways of playing around with the data?

Comment: @Meki21 That's rather too broad to answer specifically. At least, I can't think of any suggestions with only that for a prompt.